# Laravel 5.5 Data is being inserted twice in database

Tags: laravel

This code enters multiple products in orders table, but what strange thing is happening is if i insert 2 products, data is being entered 4 times, if i insert 1 product it is being inerted 2 times. What is wrong with this code ?

```
foreach($request->product_id as $rpk => $rpv)

    {
        $data = new Order();
        $data->user_id = $request->customer_id[$rpk];
        $data->status = $request->status[$rpk];
        $data->save();

        Order::where('id', $data->id)->update(['order_number' => $data->id]);

        // For OrderDetail
        $detail = new OrderDetail();
        $detail->customer_id = $request->customer_id[$rpk];
        $detail->order_id = $data->id;
        $detail->product_id = $request->product_id[$rpk];
        $detail->price = $request->price[$rpk];
        $detail->quantity = $request->quantity[$rpk];
        $detail->total = $request->total[$rpk];
        $detail->comment = $request->comment[0];
        $detail->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $detail->bill_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //$detail->sales_tax = '13'; // Need to change this
        $success = $detail->save();


    }
```

Comment: That's may be because of the `foreach($request->product_id as $rpk => $rpv)`

Comment: make dd($request->product_id) and  make sure that data you sent equal the data you receive in your controller

Comment: You should really debug the `$request` variable, like suggested above.

Comment: It seems your relations ship between the order and the order detail is always 1 to 1 as you are creating one order and one order detail  in the same for loop. If this is the case, why do two tables instead of 1? Back to your question, make `dd($request->product_id)` and ensure that you have the expected number of products. The loop itself is fine and should work, i will start by questioning what is being passed from the `$request`

Comment: how many times it is going inside loop?

Comment: when i insert 2 items dd is giving 0
1
array:2 [▼
  0 => "4"
  1 => "7"
] but data is inserted 2 times in database